# Can someone explain the detail of the proof (rectifiable curve)

Tags: real-analysis, plane-curves, curves, bounded-variation

Curve $C$ in the plain,
\begin{align} C:=
\begin{cases}
x=\phi(t) \\ y=\psi(t)
\end{cases}
\quad, \quad a \le t \le b
\end{align}

The graph of C is $\{(x, y): x=\phi(t), y=\psi(t), a\le t\le b\}$

$\Gamma=\{t_0=a, t_1, \cdots, t_m=b\}$ is a partition of [a, b]

The corresponding points $P_i=\left(\phi(t_i), \psi(t_i)\right), i=0, \cdots, m$ on the graph $C$.

$l$ is the length,
$$
l(\Gamma)=\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{\left[\phi(t_i)-\phi(t_{i-1})\right]^2 \left[\psi(t_i)-\psi(t_{i-1}) \right]^2}
$$

$L$ is the length of the curve $C$,
$$L=L(C)=\sup_\Gamma l(\Gamma)$$

If $\lim_{|\Gamma|\to0}l(\Gamma)$ exists, then $C$ is called rectifiable curve.

---

### Theorem

$C$ is rectifiable *if and only if* both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are of bounded variation. Moreover,
$$V(\phi), V(\psi)\le L \le V(\phi)+V(\psi)$$

---

### Proof

1. for real $a$, $b$,$$|a|, |b| \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \le |a|+|b|$$
2. If $C$ is rectifiable and $\Gamma=\{t_i\}$ is a partition of $[a, b]$, then the inequality of l
   $$l(\Gamma)=\sum_i \sqrt{\left[\phi(t_i)-\phi(t_{i-1})\right]^2+\left[\psi(t_i)-\psi(t_{i-1})\right]^2}\le L$$
   implies
   $$\sum |\phi(t_i) - \phi(t_{i-1})| \le L \quad \text{and} \quad \sum |\psi(t_i) - \psi(t_{i-1})| \le L$$
3. Hence, $V(\phi), V(\psi) \le L$
4. On the other hand, for any $C$, 
   $$l(\Gamma) \le \sum |\phi(t_i) - \phi(t_{i-1})| + \sum |\psi(t_i) - \psi(t_{i-1})| \le V(\phi) + V(\psi)$$
5. Hence, $L \le V(\phi) + V(\psi)$
6. By 3 and 6 process, $$V(\phi), V(\psi)\le L \le V(\phi)+V(\psi)$$

---

I do not understand process 5. How can we get $L \le V(\phi) + V(\psi)$?
which one is correct?
$$l(\Gamma) \le \sum |\phi(t_i) - \phi(t_{i-1})| + \sum |\psi(t_i) - \psi(t_{i-1})| \le L \le V(\phi) + V(\psi)$$
$$l(\Gamma) \le L \le \sum |\phi(t_i) - \phi(t_{i-1})| + \sum |\psi(t_i) - \psi(t_{i-1})| \le V(\phi) + V(\psi)$$

Can you explain why it does?

Comment: No, in 4, you can calculates sup (over gamma) and then L\leq V(phi)+V(psi)

Comment: @vvnitram Yeap, I agree that $l(\Gamma) \le L$ since $L$ is supremum of $l(\Gamma)$. However, How can I guarantee that $L\le V(\phi)+V(\psi)$?

Comment: In 4 you obtained that for all gamma, L(gamma)\leq V(phi)+v(psi). Now, the sup of L(gamma) must be leq too